# Backslash escape not working in HTML attributes

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, backslash, html-escape

I tried below code for checking whether backslashes in HTML attribute value makes the character next to it escape:

```
<button id="b1" onclick="$('body').append('<button onclick=alert(\'something\');>')">test</button>
```

Here, if backslash works, then when we click over #b1 , a new button should have appended to  and when we click over that new button, a new alert should have popped up. But it didn't. This means backslash escape won't work in HTML attributes. 
Is it correct?
Then how do I escape things ?

When I tried opening that webpage with *view-source:* prefix, I saw code like below one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>
   Hi there!
  </title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="jQuery.js"></script>
  <style>
    .red{color: red;} 
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <button id="b1" onclick="$('body').append('<button onclick=alert(+AFw'something+AFw');>test</button>')">
    test
  </button>
  <script src="question.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here, backslashes are replaced to **+AFW**. Is it wrong ?
Also, if I try changing the onclick attribute value to `doIt();` and add below code into question.js file, it works perfectly:

```
function doIt(){
    alert("<button onclick=\"alert('hi');\"> ");
}
```

But as the question says, we have to find out why backslash escape not working in HTML attribute values. Also, I wants to define what will happen when button clicked, right in the attribute.

Thanks in advance for giving informations.....

Comment: Is it any kind bug of HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Seems working. Here's the runnable script/example

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="b1" onclick="$('body').append('<button onclick=alert(\'something\');>test</button>')">test</button>
```

Comment: No bro! it didn't.